# python bigquery get external table meta data

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I want to get the external meta data of a table created in bigquery. The table was created like this:

```
table_ref = self._client.dataset('test').table('test')
table = bigquery.Table(table_ref)

self._extconfig = bigquery.ExternalConfig('AVRO')
self._extconfig.autodetect = True
self._extconfig.source_uris = ['gs://someproject/bucket/dir/file*.avro']
table.external_data_configuration = self._extconfig
self._client.create_table(table)
```

Now i want to access the meta data stored in `external_data_configuration'` like this:

```
dataset = self._client.dataset('test')
table_ref = dataset.table('test')
table = bigquery.Table(table_ref)
print(table.table_id)
print(table.path)
print(table.table_type)
print(table.external_data_configuration)
```

But all i receive is None for table_type, where i would expect 'AVRO' and also None for external_data_configuration.

Is there a way to get the external_data_configuration, especially the `source_uris` for external tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
dataset = self._client.dataset('test')
table_ref = dataset.table('test')
table = self._client.get_table(table_ref)
print(table.external_data_configuration.source_uris)
```

The `get_table` will fetch all the information of the table into the `table` variable.